# Create an RSS Element with Namespace using SimpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to create a rss feed and one element is

```
<content:encoded></content:encoded>
```

But, when i use this code:

```
$item->addChild('content:encoded',htmlspecialchars($itemdata->description));
```

I get this as a result:

```
<encoded> .................. </encoded>
```

I don't get the content namespace, and how would I be able to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php), you need to provide the namespace URI as 3rd argument of `addChild()` to create element in namespace correctly :

```
$item->addChild(
        'content:encoded',
        htmlspecialchars($itemdata->description),
        'namespace-URI-for-content-prefix-here'
    );
```

---

**Quick demo :**

```
$raw = '<root xmlns:content="mynamespace"></root>';
$item = new SimpleXMLElement($raw);
$item->addChild(
          'content:encoded',
          'foo bar baz',
          'mynamespace'
      );
echo $item->asXML();
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/548321)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:content="mynamespace"><content:encoded>foo bar baz</content:encoded></root>
```